# Integrating with a Square Root

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^12t^3\sqrt{4t^2+4}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Can I get a hint about how to attempt to integrate this? I'm kinda rusty with integrals.

Comment: Change of variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Let $\sqrt{4t^2+4}=u\implies4t^2+4=u^2, t^2=\dfrac{u^2-4}4$

$8t\ dt=2u\ du\implies t\ dt=\dfrac{u\ du}4$

Comment: Great! I forgot how flexible changing variables can be.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate hint: let $t=\tan\theta$ and you'll have an integral of $$c\tan^3\theta\sec^3\theta\,d\theta=c(\sec^2\theta-1)\sec^2\theta\,(\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta)$$